# Heapsort for arbitrary ranges in Java

Tags: java, sorting, heap

I plan to work on Introsort, which requires a working implementation of heap sort. Also, the heap sort implementation must be able to sort arbitrary ranges within an array, which, in turn, requires some more involved index manipulation.

**Heapsort.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.util.sorting;

/**
 * This class implements heap sort.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Heapsort {

    /**
     * Sorts the entire integer array.
     * 
     * @param array the array to sort.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts a particular range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], 
     * ..., array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array     the array containing the target range.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the target range.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the target range.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        // CLRS says 'BUILD-MAX-HEAP' is O(n).
        buildMaxHeap(array, fromIndex, toIndex);

        // And this is O(n log n).
        for (int i = toIndex - 1; i > fromIndex; --i) {
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[fromIndex];
            array[fromIndex] = tmp;
            maxSiftDown(array, fromIndex, i, 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes sure the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
     * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]} forms a maximum heap.
     * 
     * @param array     the array holding the target range.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the range to rebuild
     *                  as a heap.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the range to rebuild as 
     *                  a heap.
     */
    private static void buildMaxHeap(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        int rangeLength = toIndex - fromIndex;

        for (int i = rangeLength / 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            maxSiftDown(array, fromIndex, toIndex, i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sifts down the element {@code array[index]} in order to restore the max
     * heap property. The heap is assumed to occupy the range 
     * {@code array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array     the array holding the heap.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the heap.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the heap.
     * @param index     the index of the element to sift down.
     */
    private static void maxSiftDown(int[] array, 
                                    int fromIndex, 
                                    int toIndex,
                                    int index) {
        int leftChildIndex = left(index);
        // Right child index is one position from left child index towards 
        // larger indices.
        int rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
        int maxChildIndex = index;
        // Save the array component we want to sift down.
        int target = array[fromIndex + index];

        for (;;) {
            if (fromIndex + leftChildIndex < toIndex 
                    && array[fromIndex + leftChildIndex] > target) {
                maxChildIndex = leftChildIndex;
            }

            if (maxChildIndex == index) {
                if (fromIndex + rightChildIndex < toIndex
                        && array[fromIndex + rightChildIndex] > target) {
                    maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }
            } else {
                if (fromIndex + rightChildIndex < toIndex
                        && array[fromIndex + rightChildIndex] > 
                           array[fromIndex + leftChildIndex]) {
                    maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }
            }

            if (maxChildIndex == index) {
                // No swap. Just insert the sifted element.
                array[fromIndex + maxChildIndex] = target;
                return;
            }

            // No swap here neither. 
            // Just move up the maximum to current position.
            array[fromIndex + index] = array[fromIndex + maxChildIndex];

            index = maxChildIndex;
            leftChildIndex = left(index);
            rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the left child of the element at index 
     * {@code index}.
     * 
     * @param index the index of the target element.
     * @return the index of the left child of the target element.
     */
    private static int left(int index) {
        return (index << 1) + 1;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import net.coderodde.util.sorting.Heapsort;

/**
 * This class implements a demonstration of Introsort's and heap sort's 
 * performance as compared to {@link java.util.Arrays.sort}.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Demo {

    private static final int LENGTH = 500000;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 30;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        long totalArraysSort = 0L;
        long totalHeapsort = 0L;

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < ITERATIONS; ++iteration) {
            int[] array1 = getRandomIntegerArray(LENGTH, random);
            int[] array2 = array1.clone();

            int fromIndex = random.nextInt(LENGTH / 10);
            int toIndex = LENGTH - random.nextInt(LENGTH / 10);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Arrays.sort(array1, fromIndex, toIndex);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            totalArraysSort += endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Arrays.sort in " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                               " milliseconds.");

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Heapsort.sort(array2, fromIndex, toIndex);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            totalHeapsort += endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Heapsort.sort in " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                               " milliseconds");

            System.out.println("Arrays identical: " + Arrays.equals(array1, 
                                                                    array2));
            System.out.println("---");
        }

        System.out.println("Total Arrays.sort time:   " + totalArraysSort + 
                           " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println("Total Heapsort.sort time: " + totalHeapsort +
                           " milliseconds.");
    }

    private static int[] getRandomIntegerArray(int size, Random random) {
        return IntStream.range(0, size)
                        .map((i) -> random.nextInt(2 * size))
                        .toArray();
    }
}
```

After I run the `Demo`, it prints:

> ```
> Total Arrays.sort time:   1929 milliseconds.
> Total Heapsort.sort time: 3588 milliseconds.
> ```

Slower, but no can do. Hopefully introsort may come closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Rearranging if statements

This series of if statements puzzled me for a while:

> ```
>         if (fromIndex + leftChildIndex < toIndex 
>                 && array[fromIndex + leftChildIndex] > target) {
>             maxChildIndex = leftChildIndex;
>         }
>
>         if (maxChildIndex == index) {
>             if (fromIndex + rightChildIndex < toIndex
>                     && array[fromIndex + rightChildIndex] > target) {
>                 maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
>             }
>         } else {
>             if (fromIndex + rightChildIndex < toIndex
>                     && array[fromIndex + rightChildIndex] > 
>                        array[fromIndex + leftChildIndex]) {
>                 maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if (maxChildIndex == index) {
>             // No swap. Just insert the sifted element.
>             array[fromIndex + maxChildIndex] = target;
>             return;
>         }
> ```

I know what it is doing - it's finding the maximum child (if any).  It's just that certain branches when taken should mean that other branches are not reachable.  For example, if the first `if` is taken, it means that the left child is a valid child.  But that means that it can't be the case that `maxChildIndex == index`, which is checked immediately after.

In the worst case, the code has to go through 4 `if` statements.  But I would rearrange the order of the `if` statements to prevent unnecessary checks, which reduces the worst case to 2 `if` statements:

```
        if (fromIndex + leftChildIndex < toIndex
                && array[fromIndex + leftChildIndex] > target) {
            maxChildIndex = leftChildIndex;
            if (fromIndex + rightChildIndex < toIndex
                    && array[fromIndex + rightChildIndex] >
                       array[fromIndex + leftChildIndex]) {
                maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
            }
        } else {
            if (fromIndex + rightChildIndex < toIndex
                    && array[fromIndex + rightChildIndex] > target) {
                maxChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
            } else {
                // No swap. Just insert the sifted element.
                array[fromIndex + maxChildIndex] = target;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much comment on the algorithm itself.

Java benchmarking is notoriously tricky since it does on-the-fly optimization. 
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103) for example.

I would make `Demo` an actual class. I would not hard code `LENGTH` and `ITERATION` since you might want to benchmark with various values.

You might want to benchmark more than Arrays.sort and Heapsort.sort.  So instead of hard coding those sorting functions, 
you can define a function `Map<String, Double> benchmark(Map<String, Consumer<int[]>>... sortingFunctions)`.
`Arrays::sort` and `Heapsort::sort` are instances of `Consumer<int[]>`.